# codeigniter image upload (get the crypted name)

Tags: database, codeigniter, submit

I want to upload images to my server and it works fine and I have encrypted the name on the images.

But now I want to update the user table in my database so I can show the image on the users' profile.

My problem is that I can't find out how to insert the encrypted image name in the database table called "users" and the felt Field in users table is "profile_picture".

I have tried this

```
$profilBilledNavn = $this->upload->data('file_name');
$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
$this->db->update('users', $profilBilledNavn);
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi simon: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174176/get-file-name-after-configencrypt-name-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You have to show us some code, but anyway you need to set the `encrypt_name` when uploading the file:

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

EDIT:
Based on your update, your code should read:

```
$profilBilledNavn['profile_picture'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
$this->db->update('users', $profilBilledNavn);
```

EDIT 2:
Please note that `$this->upload->data()` would return an *array* holding info of the file uploaded, [refer](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).
So what you need to do is:

```
$file_array = $this->upload->data('file_name');
```

and then use:

```
$profilBilledNavn['profile_picture'] = $file_array['file_name'];
```

Now Pay attention for the documentation:

> **file_name**     The name of the file that
>   was uploaded including the file
>   extension.
>   **orig_name**     The original
>   file name. This is only useful if you
>   use the encrypted name option.

So since you are using `encrypt_name` you should use the first option (`file_name`) to update your DB.

Comment: i have updated my questing and i have encrypet it, i just want to update my user table in my database to the encrypted name

Comment: i got this error after i try your example Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `users` SET `profile_picture` = Array WHERE `username` = 'simonj'

Comment: @simon: of course it won't work! sorry was looking to the `"encrypt file" bit, and didn't notice that you are adding the whole array. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Refer here for a better clarity

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Lets say that you have the upload data in an array called upload_data.

Load database class

> $this->load->database();

then in model or controller ..

inserts into the field called cryptedname in your table

> $cryptednamme =
>   $upload_data['file_name'];
>   $this->db->set('cryptedname',
>   $cryptedname);

Insert into the table called image

> $this->db->insert('image');

Comment: okay i can still not do it :S i have this         $profilBilledNavn = $this->upload->data('file_name');
  $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
  $this->db->update('users', $profilBilledNavn);

Comment: @simon: huh?!! can you edit your question and add you code..and actually explaining what are you doing or trying to do!