# get file name after $config['encrypt_name'] using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there anyway for me to get the file_name of the file after it was encrypted so that i can save the filename to my database.

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

this encrypt is generally change the file name of the image file. I wonder how can I get it or probably save it to a variable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$this->upload->data();

This is a helper function that returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded. Here is the array prototype:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

so you can acces  like  $uploaded=$this->upload->data();
$uploaded['file_name']... etc

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Thanks , this function actually shows me the encrypted name which i was looking for

Answer (score -2):

You can get the file name from php $_FILES global array 'file_name' index.

```
<?php 
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['file_name'];
?>
```

Comment: I tried to do that but still got error. Undefined index: file_name and file.